# How do I use zu/zur in "Go to secure payment" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, dative

We have a button that needs to say "Go to secure payment". I tried to research myself:

- Google Translate [says](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=de&text=Go%20to%20Secure%20Payment) *Gehen Sie zu Sichere Zahlung* which is too much for a button
- Tried reducing the above to *Zu Sichere Zahlung gehen*, or even *Zu Sichere Zahlung*, but something feels wrong about the word endings
- Moreover, [this article](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/german/german-zu/) says the ending of *zu* depends on the gender of the word after it, and since *payment* [ends with *-ung* and therefore is feminine](https://jakubmarian.com/words-ending-with-ung-are-feminine-in-german/), should it not be *zur Zahlung*?

**UPDATE**. As I was writing this, I discovered that if I change my original text to lowercase, Google Translate [starts suggesting](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=de&text=Go%20to%20secure%20payment) *Gehen Sie zur sicheren Zahlung*, which feels more like it, but I still don't trust it.

Please confirm if *Zur sicheren Zahlung* is the right form? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

*Zur sicheren Zahlung* is fine and the shorter form, without *gehen* is more fluent, more common, too.

The reason (die Zahlung, fem.) is right, too.

Comment: Danke schön! I will accept the answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I find your proposal an unattractive mix of marketing assurance (Die Zahlung ist sicher) and actual navigation. I recommend to take a look at some German online shops, but typical labels are:

- (Zum) Warenkorb (To shopping cart)
- Kontrolle/Überprüfen (final check, somewhat optional).
- Zur Kasse (to payment, on that page you can still elaborate on the security, but most likely the SSL/TLS icon is already inidcating this)

Comment: I would prefer this because people either know how to identify a secure payment or they have no idea what is so "secure" and you will need more words to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

A contextual translation would be

> Zur abgesicherten Zahlung

What is the difference to `Zur sicheren Zahlung`?

(My assumption is) You want to point out that the connection is secured and that the customer should feel safe that no one is interupting the payment process.

With "sichere Zahlung" it get also implied that the customer will pay "for sure" - whilst a usual online shop still has a "cancel" button, this would somehow play with words.

Thus feel - for me as native speaker - a bit "awkward"/ let me smile.

As [guidot](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56558/36160) pointed out: have a look at german online shops and and realize:

> Zur Kasse / Weiter zur Kasse

is quite common. All hints for "secure" are "scattered randomly" around these buttons.

btw. the last button - by law ([§312j BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__312j.html)) - requires to have a writing that using it the sale contract ([§433 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__433.html)) comes into effect. E.g. `Kostenpflichtig bestellen`.

So if the link to the payment is something else than starting the contract, it should be fine to say "Zur abgesicherten Zahlung". If you need to establish the contract, you need sth. like "Zahlungspflichtig bestellen" first. (See e.g. [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button-L%C3%B6sung))

Comment: +1 for mentioning §312j (3)!

Answer (score 0):

“Zur sicheren Zahlung” would be grammatically correct; Idiomatically, however, this looks like a bad translation and not like real German. If I was to proof-read the translation, I would suggest that the text be changed.

Options that I would accept as idiomatically correct would be:

• Jetzt sicher bezahlen
• Weiter zur Zahlung
• Jetzt bezahlen

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. If you want to keep it as an answer, please edit your answer. Enrich it with reasons why you think that fits the OP question as an heloful answer. In case you just wanted to leave a note - please consider gaining reputation first so that you can comment.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Whether a valid answer or not, this certainly is nothing that should be posted as a comment (at least on the question).